# Make call from iphone application programmatically

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, call

I'm developing iphone application and i'm having label with phone number, i need to make a call from user touch on phone number. I tried with following code but didn't make call, i'm currently checking with xcode simulator.

My code,

in my header file

```
IBOutlet UILabel* lableMakeCall1;

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView* lableMakeCall1;
```

And my .m file contains

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
lableMakeCall1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = \
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapLabelWithGesture1:)];
    [lableMakeCall1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
}

- (void)didTapLabelWithGesture1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture1 {
    NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:lableMakeCall1.text];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];

/*
I tried in this code also
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:lableMakeCall1.text];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];*/

}
```

Comment: In addition, the [spec says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1) that you use `tel:<NUMBER>`, i.e. no double forward slash, but you have to test on a phone, or if you use a `facetime:` link, then you can test on ann ipod/ipad

Comment: Also make sure there are no spaces in the phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test this on an iPhone as you cannot make calls on the iOS Simulator. You also cannot make calls on iPod Touch and iPad.